# How to create External data-source in html5

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

In html5 the input field has the following format

```
 <input type='text', data-provide= "typeahead", data-items="4",
 autocomplete="off",  data-source='["Business and Commercial Laws",
 "Consumer Laws", "Criminal Laws"]', name='userInputName',
 placeholder='Court of practice'> Data </input>
```

How do i create link the above  tag with a `data-source` which is not inline, but external. I ultimately want to re-use the data-source.

Edit:
I am using the `typeahead` plugin in bootstrap. I am programming in node.js framework. So i can use

`- var ArrayVar = [ "this", "that", "here"]`

```
 data-source='#{ArrayVar}'
```

But the above converts array `ArrayVar` into a string `"this, that, here"` which is not desired, as the `data-source` should be an array.

Comment: What do you mean by "not inline, but external."  Create what kind of link?

Comment: The above code shows `data-source` defined inline inside the `input` tag. I want to provide a link elsewhere, like above inside `script` tag or in another file

Comment: By link you mean `<a>`?  What does that have to do with `data-source`?

Comment: no i mean `data-source = "external link"`The external link can be variable defined inside `script` tag, perhaps. If that would work.

Comment: Are you using some special plugin/framework to evaluate those attributes? `data-source` is no specific HTML5 input attribute. Btw, `<input/>` tags should be empty.

Comment: I am using angularjs in nodejs

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to evaluate var Array in nodejs, at client side?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18491057/how-to-evaluate-var-array-in-nodejs-at-client-side)

Answer (score 1):

Data attributes can be retrived with jQuery.

```
$('[data-source']).each(function(){ // select all elements with the data-source attribute
    var $this = $(this), source = $this.data("source");

    // update the source
    $this.data("source", sourceToArray(source));
});
```

Fitting this into a framework might be difficult, so I suggest choosing an unused attribute, or making sure that this code fires before AngularJS is loaded.