# How to evaluate var Array in nodejs, at client side?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, twitter-bootstrap

The statement

```
- var X = [ "a", "b", "c"]
```

when evaluated using `#{X}` converts `X` it into string "a, b, c".

how to evaluate X without converting it into String?

Note: i'm using a bootstrap plug in which demands an Array as input.

```
<input data-source='["a", "b", "c"]' >
```

Here I am trying to substitute the above array with `X`. But like mentioned above, the `#{X}` operation converts it into a sting, rather than deliver an array to `data-source`.

Comment: Attributes can only be strings.  What is the current vs. desired output?

Comment: You mean `#{JSON.stringify(X)}`?

Comment: current output is  string `"a, b, c"`. desired output is array `[ "a", "b", "c"]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) to convert your Array to a JSON/string representation:

```
var X = JSON.stringify( [ "a", "b", "c"] ); // yields '["a", "b", "c"]'
```